# Cannot build the Selendroid server APK for application '...'

Tags: android, selenium, testing, appium, selendroid

Hi everyone I'm trying to Run a tester with selendroid to test an app on my device.
the selendroid server is running on  *PORT 4444* and the test script is correct but when I'm trying to run the test script by TestNG these errors shown in Console :

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>   FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Cannot build the Selendroid server APK for application 'io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp@37f09ad0': Error executing shell command: C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe package -M C:\Users\NP\AppData\Local\Temp\io.selendroid.testapp1545829318250\AndroidManifest.xml -I C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\platforms\android-24\android.jar -F C:\Users\NP\AppData\Local\Temp\io.selendroid.testapp1545829318250\manifest.apk -f
>   Command duration or timeout: 33.59 seconds
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'Shakib', ip: '192.168.73.45', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
>   Driver info: io.selendroid.client.SelendroidDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>   Caused by: io.selendroid.server.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Cannot build the Selendroid server APK for application 'io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp@37f09ad0': Error executing shell command: C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe package -M C:\Users\NP\AppData\Local\Temp\io.selendroid.testapp1545829318250\AndroidManifest.xml -I C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk-essential\platforms\android-24\android.jar -F C:\Users\NP\AppData\Local\Temp\io.selendroid.testapp1545829318250\manifest.apk -f

I really don't know why the APK is not being installed
does anyone know how can I fix this?
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason for using Selendroid, its very old mobile automation tool which works for devices with API version <17 i.e. Android 4.2 ( JELLY_BEAN_MR1).

Answer (score 0):

Selendroid supports API level from 10-19 so it might be possible that your apk file is build with higher Android API versions.